# Showing all my database(MyDatanase.mdf) tables in to comboBox1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[image][image]

Things I did,

> 1. In Sql I have created a database name: MyDb,
> 2. I have created a application which can create any number of Tables in MyDb
> 3. Now I want to show my all tables in one`comboBox1`(not values or columns).

Showing all my `database(dbNames.mdf)` tables in to `comboBox1` not **column names**. 
I used this code for binding the `dbNames` Tables value. But I need the Tables not the values or anything. Please Help.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String strConnection = "Data Source=HP\\SQLEXPRESS;database=Mydb;Integrated Security=true";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
        try
        {

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();

            sqlCmd.Connection = con;
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select Tables from MyDb.tables";

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);

            DataTable dtRecord = new DataTable();
            sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
            comboBox1.DataSource = dtRecord;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLES";
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the information stored in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, i.e. you could use this query, in MS SQL Server use simply:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

to get all the tables in the current database. You find the table name in the column TABLE_NAME, so you would best use:

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES";
```

in your code instead of

```
sqlCmd.CommandText = "Select Tables from MyDb.tables";
```

and set the DisplayMember property to the column name with

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
```

instead.

Comment: MyDb is my database.. You are trying to tell me that i should use it in the commandText?

Comment: its not working. But if i use sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"; Its binding something i.e,. System.Data.DataRowView

Comment: Why Its coming like this... ?

Comment: It's because you're using MS SQL Server as I noticed just now, but tagged MySQL instead. The syntax of T-SQL is a bit different.

Comment: So You are telling that i Cannot do that ?

Comment: Yah its called *(all) i used it already, both are the same... thank you, but it even showing something wait i m uploading the error please see, that you will get what is happening.

Comment: I have uploaded it. Please check @VMai

Comment: If you check the output, it's the column TABLE_NAME, so it's better to select only this column.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that the DisplayMember property got to set to the right column name, here the column with the name TABLE_NAME.

Comment: Now is there any solution ?

Comment: I must have accidently not saved the edit, but now it should show up. I'm sorry.

Comment: yup now its working... did u know how to select the tables to save values in it.?

Comment: I'm glad that it worked now. As I was closing a lot of browser tabs I found the one with the not saved edit too. But now you have a different question. You should therefor ask a new question. Make sure you ask a good one. Include what you want to do and what you have tried so far, just as you've done here.